# Precedence of Spring Transaction Isolation level vs Database isolation level

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-transactions, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

Say, the isolation level for a database is set at `READ_COMMITED`.
**Then through spring transaction management I am setting the transaction Isolation level to**
1) `READ_UNCOMMITED`   -  then what will be the effective isolation level for this transaction.
2) `REPEATABLE_READ`  - then what will be the effective isolation level for this transaction.

Comment: A good question - why don't you test it? Although, my guess would be that spring changes the session level database isolation mode. You can test that by changing the isolation mode in spring and then query the session level database setting via sql from spring.

Answer (score 2):

There is default isolation level set in DB (in your case it is READ_COMMITED) and one transaction isolation level. If it's not explicitly specified default level is used.

Spring just turns on declared isolation level and of course "overrides" default level of DB.

In fact you can do the same without spring by calling SQL

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

Spring just does the same for you

Comment: cool. so spring's transaction isolation settings take precedence for that particular transaction. Gr8.